# Advice on using aggregation more efficiently

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm currently trying to build a sports website where people can vote on how much a certain player is likely to win a match over another player. It is going to be centered around tennis, so the matches will all be 1:1, but the problem i'm running into is compiling consolidated results from my user data set.

I'm currently using MongoDB and i'm pretty much a beginner in it. My goal for the final results would be things such as tallying the total number of each vote type for each individual matching of each player (wow). So in order to do this, I noticed that the aggregation framework seemed to be the tool i'm supposed to use. With that being said, I successfully achieved what I set out to do in the end, but i'm wondering if there's a "better" way to use the aggregation tool than how I ended up with. Let me explain, so here is the normal structure of a single User in my Users collection:

```
{
 name: 'something',
 players: {
  federer: {
   mannarino: -2,
   seppi: 1
   }
  mannarino: {
   federer: 2,
   seppi: 2
  }
  seppi: {
  federer: -1,
  mannarino: -2
  }
 }
}
```

So as you can see, users can rate the chances of winning of any match accordingly for each tennis player (on scale of -2 "Highly disagree to win" to 2 "Highly agree to win")

Now, to go over the entire list to find the totals for each tennis player, I need to iterate through each player and then iterate Again through all their respective interactions. That's a double for loop that looks like:

```
for each target player {
  for each opponent against target player {
    Users.aggregate();
 }
}
```

I simplified it greatly because i'm not at my main computer now with my code, but hopefully the idea still comes across. I can replace the above pseudo code with the actual code for more clarification when I get back home if needed.

Now, the aggregate results in tallying up each kind of vote (5 kinds of votes, between -2, -1, 0, 1, 2) in the target:opponent pairing and returns it at the end, where I can do things like find the average quality of the interaction.

The problem is that my aggregation command is running quite a large amount of times. Right now, i'm looking at the max potential tennis players in my database will be around ~80. If it's 80, that means that, to run this function and create my consolidated statistics out of my user input data, i'd have to do 6400 (80 x 80) aggregations! Now like I said, i'm still a beginner with mongodb, but is this normal to run so many? I tried running it on my computer and it seemed like it took awhile with just 5 tennis players available (25 total runs of aggregation, 5 x 5).

Is there a better way to use aggregation here, or is this really the only solution I have for creating my statistics? Is there some way I can use aggregation to get the totals of an entire player's interactions with every other player in a single aggregation instead of 80++ aggregations?

So I could, for example, remove the need to loop twice.

```
for each target player {
    Users.aggregate();
}
```

So instead of doing 6400 aggregations, i'd only need to do 80. I feel like that would be a lot more efficient, but i'm not sure how to structure my aggregation to accomplish that, or if that is something the aggregation framework is even capable of doing.

In any case, like I said, the way I structured it "works"... but i'm just wondering if there's a better way I could be doing this. Thanks.

If I need to provide any extra clarification please let me know.

Comment: This is a structural problem more than anything. Your data **should** be stored like this instead `"players": [{ "name": "federer", "vs": "mannarino", "score": -2 },{ "name": "federer", "vs": "seppi", "score": 1 }, { "name": "mannarino", "vs": "federer", "score": 2 }, ...etc... ]` or even with those array members as separate documents in another collection depending on your actual needs. You can use `$objectToArray` in an aggregation pipeline in order to manipulate the current structure into something like the above and then build the remaining aggregation off of that, but better to convert.

Comment: The basic thing is "named keys" whilst nice and quick for "client side" lookup and retrieval of data, is just not the optimal way to store and use data within a "database". For a "database" you want a more natural "record structure", which is done rather as demonstrated above either as array members or discreet documents in their own collection.